# Search Scala symbol documentation such as %% and %

Tags: scala, scalatra

Not entirely sure how to query for a search on `%%` and `%` which I see being used in Scalatra. Trying to understand what significance these symbols have in Scala. Is there a tool out there where I can put in the symbol and it'll pull up the appropriate documentation?

Comment: http://symbolhound.com/ is a search engine that doesn't ignore special characters, but it is limited only to Stack Overflow, so there is small number of posts about this framework.

Comment: It's often helpful for me to use `eclipse with-source=true` in sbt, import the project in Eclipse, click on the symbol and then use "Open Declaration (F3)" to navigate to the documentation of the symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't have any significance in the language - they are just variable or method names like foo or bar. I don't know anything about Scalatra, but if you try the [Scalatra documentation](http://www.scalatra.org/2.0/api/index.html#org.scalatra.package) there's an alphabetical index in the top left that you can check (the `#` before `A` is for symbols). It doesn't turn up anything. Are you sure they are being used in Scalatra, and not just in the sbt build file? Because in sbt they are used for managed dependencies - [docs here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Library-Dependencies).

Comment: Yeah, they're sbt specific - was hard to tell since both tools are new to me. Thanks Luigi.